# Get a segment fault while reading a file

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault

I want to read the whole file content and print it out , but I get a segment fault , I can't find what's wrong with the code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * file;
    long fsize;
    file = fopen("./input.txt","r");
    if(file != NULL){

        //get file size
        fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
        fsize = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);

        // print
        char * file_content;
        fgets(file_content,fsize,file);
        puts(file_content);
    }
    else{
        printf("open failure\n");
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger and looked at where it crashes?..

Comment: What's the size of you input buffer?

Comment: @dmaij I don't use buffer ..

Comment: Actually, you do, but it's not initialized. The answer is already there. This looks like a homework assignment, so I expect you to think and learn, no offense, just helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer you pass to `fgets` (`file_content`) is uninitialized. It should be pointing to a block of memory large enough to contain the specified number (`fsize`) of bytes. You can use `malloc` to allocate the memory.

```
char* file_content = (char*)malloc(fsize);
```

Answer (score 2):

char * file_content is just a pointer, you need to allocate memory to store the string.

```
char * file_content;
file_content = malloc(fsize);
```

Answer (score 1):

*"..but I get a segment fault"*

Obviously because you're attempting to write to an uninitialized `file_content`

Allocated memory for `file_content` before use

```
char * file_content =malloc(fsize);
```