# SEGFAULT attempting fgetc to read from pipe

Tags: c, process, segmentation-fault, fgetc

Currently, I have a parent process piping information to children and reading out of their STDOUT through `fgetc`. I iterate through rounds and store the file pointer from the first round using `fdopen` and call it again in the next round.

The issue is, in the first round the `read_line` results in a perfectly fine read, but in the second round the fgetc hits a segfault.

Error Message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7791330 in __GI___uflow (fp=0x6041b0) at genops.c:381
381     return *(unsigned char *) fp->_IO_read_ptr++;
```

Reading Function: (I know it's not the best)
To Clarify. It works the first time. Why won't it work the second?
Many other questions seem to just have a different error.

```
char* read_line(FILE* file,int currentP, Players *players) {
    char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
    int position = 0;
    int next = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < players->players[currentP].position; i++) {
        next = fgetc(file);
    }
    while (1) {
        next = fgetc(file);
        //players->players[currentP].position++;
        if (next == '!') {
            return "!";
        }
        if (next == EOF || next == '\n') {
            result[position] = '\0';
            return result;
        } else {
            result[position++] = (char)next;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a segment fault while reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701924/get-a-segment-fault-while-reading-a-file)

Comment: You have no check for buffer overflow. And when catching the crash in a debugger, where in *your* code does it happen? What is the input you read? How do you call your function? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: maybe file handler is closed and you tried to read from broken handler. so error is not in function provided but in code above.

Comment: Warning, when returning `"!"`, your lost the position of allocated memory, and you won't be able to `free()` what `read_line` returns

Comment: Turns out the issue was my result variable wasn't being memset back to an empty string, so it was hitting a segfault. Adding memset solved my problem but I will try to fix memory leaks.